# pip install atuopy failed

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, autopy

```
C:\\Users\\BoBo\>pip install autopy
Collecting autopy
Using cached autopy-4.0.0.tar.gz (20 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[6 lines of output\]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\<string\>", line 2, in \<module\>
File "\<pip-setuptools-caller\>", line 34, in \<module\>
File "C:\\Users\\BoBo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-540ias0x\\autopy_48ff0273bf204c08bd6332db1d22716a\\setup.py", line 8, in \<module\>
from setuptools_rust import Binding, RustExtension
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust'
\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─\> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

[image]

```
I have tried upgrading pip, reinstalling setuptools_rust !
pip version:22.0.4
python version:Python 3.10.3
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are no pre-built wheels for python 3.10 in the  [Autopy](https://pypi.org/project/autopy/#files)  project page at PyPI.The latest support python 3.8.

So you will need to compile for your operating system.

From the documentation.First, see if a binary wheel is available for your machine by running:

```
$ pip install -U autopy
```

If that fails you'll need to install the rust compiler using [rustc](https://rustup.rs/) and then run:

```
$ rustup default nightly-2019-10-05
$ pip install -U setuptools-rust
$ pip install -U autopy
```

Another option is to build from the latest source on the GitHub repository:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/autopilot-rs/autopy-rs.git
$ cd autopy 
$ make 
$ make install
```

Comment: My boss needs me to write a program to judge whether the program is stuck by the screen. I need to use this library. Now I have changed to use pyautogui. I have never used python before, and I just found this library. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great,good to know you found a better option